# .NET: Is there a tool to list all referenced classes and methods/properties which one assembly references from another assembly?

Tags: c#, reference, signature

As the title says, but in a bit different words: I wish to generate a list of the classes and methods a C# project has referenced from another .net assembly (dll).

The reason I wish to do this, is that I have a large project which is depending on a reference which has a lot of limitations and which it would be a giant job to remove/replace. I am therefore considering rewriting said reference library myself with an identical interface (but only implementing the functionality I'm actually using in my project).

Ideally, the list should contain each class and method including signature.

If someone had an answer to this I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! This question seems to be [off-topic here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but you can try to ask in [chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), just be sure to visit their help center so you can ask an on topic and properly formatted question to their standards

Comment: You may be able to [edit] your question to instead ask "How can I find all of the referenced classes, methods, and properties?" rather than asking for a specific tool... It would be nice if you could do a little research on the subject and reference that research...

Comment: Do you have access to source code ?

Comment: NDepend is for those purposes. You might also write your own, based on libraries such as Mono Cecil.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer Yes, I have acces to the source of my own project that I want to check the dependencies of, and the referenced library of which I want to see which "components" Im referencing is open source

Comment: @Magnetron Well the idea of this site is that people can ask questions that aren't asked or answered anywhere else and then other people can learn from the same public questions and answers. Even if this is my first question here, I have saved countless hours of fault finding/research by reading other people's questions here.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you, this is well noted. I will check that out!

Comment: @thomas Still, there are topics that are off-topic. Please, [check the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specially the 4th of off-topic questions. As I said, there are better places to ask for such questions, in which you could get better answers.

Comment: @ThomasRøiriAaslund Hi, did you manage to solve this somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class implementing thin pass through methods which are identical signatures to the DLL's class methods used.   Change your application call your new class. Compile/test/etc.

Your wrapper class will show what code needs to be implemented.  This can be used to timeline and ask for developer time to replace the DLL's functionality.  For example the DLL is called in 500 places and it has 20 methods called 25 times each.

If you are fortunate, the DLL methods are static or can largely be replaced with static ones.  Static methods are much easier to replace as there is no class context to worry about.

Comment: Yes, that is excactly the idea. However the referenced library has a lot of functionality which I don't need, and that's why I want to generate a list of everything I have referenced in my own project and then see if it is possible/feasable to implement a "simplified" version of the reference library.